# AppArmor not blocking curl/ping networking when IP address used

Tags: networking, apparmor

I'm playing with network permissions in AppArmor, and I'm trying to confine this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl $SOME_IP_ADDRESS
```

If I do `curl $MY_FULL_DOMAIN`, AppArmor *does* prevent it, as it seems unable to look up an IP address. (I have noticed the same IP/hostname discrepancy with `ping` also).

My profile is like so:

```
#include <tunables/global>

/path/to/check_health.sh {
    #include <abstractions/base>
    #include <abstractions/bash>
    deny network,
    /path/to/check_health.sh r,
    /usr/bin/ping mrix,
    /usr/bin/curl mrix,
}
```

(Note the explicit, though maybe unnecessary `deny network`)

What's going on? When only an IP is used, do these programs somehow skip direct "networking", and they send requests to some file that some other unconfined program monitors? Or, maybe something about my includes allowed this, but I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Comment: I don't know if this applies in your case or not, but I have read that Debian has had an issue at the kernel level for some time that prevents AppArmor from blocking network access.